# WCF Async Service Proxy. Does 'EndXXX' close the connection?

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, wcf-client

I'm currently segregating the interface definition of a WCF web service and sorting out the client to depend on these interfaces rather than the generated service client class.

The pattern that's currently being used reads like this -

```
var client = new ServiceClient();
client.DoSomethingCompleted += (o,args) => 
{
    client.CloseAsync();
    //Do Something
}
client.DoSomething();
```

Nice and simple.  As soon as the client returns, close the connection.

By depending on the interface of the proxy you lose out on the generated events and have to use the Async Begin/End pattern.  Now it would read -

```
//client is now an IDoSomethingable
client.BeginDoSomething(new AsyncCallback((result) =>
{
    var somethingDone = client.EndDoSomething(result);
}),null);
```

So my question is **does the client get closed when 'EndDoSomething' is called** or am I missing something since there doesn't appear to be an explicit way to close it.

Much thanks in advance.